# Vtrak E610F console issues and recovery

Tags: storage-area-network, console, promise-vtrak

I have been assigned an E610F Vtrak Storage unit, the previous admin left and did not leave any documentation, so IP Address for Management and Credentials are **unknown**.

I tried using accessing the console of the controller with these settings:

- 115200
- 8 N 1
- no flow control

I get the Cli Promprt but I cannot see the boot messages, cannot input commands and cannot see the login prompt.

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6TSn.png)

Does anyone have an idea on what i can do to regain access? I think our support has ended long ago and I need to use this storage as instructed.

regards and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you do not have a proper serial cable. Other vendors have cables that look like the Promise cable, but are wired differently.

Also, the default IP for a VTrak is 10.0.0.1, if this was not changed you may be able to login to WebPAM via the ethernet port. The default 'login/password' is 'administrator/password'.

The password can be reset to default if needed, but you'll need to contact Promise technical support, you'll need a confuser file that can be installed from a lower level.

Comment: thanks rich, i will try and access it via default IP. Aside from getting a console cable from vtrak itself, is there any other way to get a hold of one?

Comment: If you do a google of "promise serial cable" there are many vendors selling them, B&H has them for $12. The search also shows SAS cables and various other cables so be sure you get the serial cable.

Comment: Let me add a few more details. Once you get a working serial cable you'll need to connect it and boot the unit, before the login prompt you will see the firmware version, you will need to get the confuser file for that firmware. The process from there is detailed [here](http://www.xsanity.com/forum/promise-technology/locked-out-promise-vtrak-e610f).

Answer (score -2):

i am also configuring Vtrack e610f, first issue i couldn't find out any cable than i went to promise support and they sent me a diagram how to prepare this cable.

so might be it will help to the guy who asked about the cable you need to have following, 
1) 6 core telephone cable with RJ11 (should have 6 cable connection)
2) RJ11 to Serial Connector (normally you have to prepare it yourself [http://www.amazon.com/InstallerParts-Female-Modular-Adapter-Ivory/dp/B008NCDN3I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008NCDN3I)

only three cables need to be setup as given below

RJ11 cable number 1 will go to serial cable port 3
RJ11 cable number 2 will go to serial cable port 2
RJ11 cable number 3 will go to serial cable port 5

and it will work.

I need a help from rich, how i can get Confuser.img files without promise technical support, since my warranty is finished.

thanks

Comment: This isn't the place to be asking for technical support and talking about warranty issues.